# JPA - query parameter is null

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hql

```
@Query("select users from User users  " +
        "where users.id like concat('%',?1,'%') and " +
        "users.name like concat('%',?2,'%') and " +
        "users.telNo like concat('%',?3,'%') ")
List<User> fuzzyQueryUser(Integer id, String name, String telNo);
```

When the first parameter `id` is null, the fuzzy query has no results. I want to have results when the parameter is null if there are entries like that in the database. What should I do? Thank you.

```
@Query("select users from User users  " +
    "where (users.id like concat('%',?1,'%') or ?1 is null or ?1 ='')and " +
    "(users.name like concat('%',?2,'%') or ?2 is null or ?2 ='') and " +
    "(users.telNo like concat('%',?3,'%') or ?3 is null or ?3 ='')")
List<User> fuzzyQueryUser(String id, String name, String telNo);
```

like this

```
@Query("select users from User users  " +
        "where (users.id like concat('%',?1,'%') or ?1 is null  )and " +
        "(users.name like concat('%',?2,'%') or ?2 is null or ?2 ='') and " +
        "(users.telNo like concat('%',?3,'%') or ?3 is null or ?3 ='')")
List<User> fuzzyQueryUser(Integer id, String name, String telNo);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add another condition to ignore null and optionally empty strings:

```
@Query("select users from User users  " +
        "where (users.id like concat('%',?1,'%') or ?1 is null) and " 
       +"users.name like concat('%',?2,'%') and " +
        "users.telNo like concat('%',?3,'%') ")
```

Comment: Amazing！Take a look at my code. In this way,I can use  three conditions for fuzzy query, and when a condition is null, the result of this condition is all values.

Comment: However, ‘id‘’ must be revised to String, rather than Integer, otherwise it will be wrong

Comment: Oh! Remove ‘ or ?1 = '' ’.  This can be used Integer, thank you very much.

Comment: yes.. in that case the last or is irrelevant.. mistaken with another string param.